# string extraction : functx:escape-for-regex() problem in Marklogic

Tags: templates, xquery, marklogic, functx

I am trying to extract text within a template in marklogic , but I got an error of :

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Lpar_, expecting Rpar_
```

I use for functx declaration .

```
<path-namespaces>
<path-namespace>
<prefix>functx</prefix>
<namespace-uri>http://www.functx.com</namespace-uri>
</path-namespace>
</path-namespaces>
```

Here is my val element where it is occur in object element

```
<val>
    substring-before(@functx:substring-after-last
    (@functx:substring-after-last("Clínica Universidad de Navarra, Pamplona, Navarra, España. Electronic address: mjyepes@unav.es.",",")
    ," ")
    ,".")
    
    declare function @functx:escape-for-regex
      ( $arg as xs:string? )  as xs:string {
    
       replace($arg,
               '(\.|\[|\]|\\|\||\-|\^|\$|\?|\*|\+|\{|\}|\(|\))','\\$1')
     } ;
    
    declare function @functx:substring-after-last
      ( $arg as xs:string? ,
        $delim as xs:string )  as xs:string {
    
       replace ("Clínica Universidad de Navarra, Pamplona, Navarra, España. Electronic address: mjyepes@unav.es.",concat('^.*',@functx:escape-for-regex($delim)),'')
     } ;
    </val>
```

Comment: Is this for a TDE? Can you provide a more complete example demonstrating how you are executing or validating the TDE i.e. https://docs.marklogic.com/tde:validate?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the "@" signs before all the function names.

Comment: It gives me : [1.0-ml] XDMP-UNBPRFX: (err:XPST0081) Prefix functx has no namespace binding

Comment: Then add a namespace binding for the `functx` namespace. (`declare namespace functx="..."`)